# Принтер esc/pos не отправляет ответа на запрос статуса

Tags: c#, esc

Здравствуйте!
Начал работать с принтером MPrint t58 через виртуальный com порт по протоколу esc/pos, печать работает нормально, но вот когда пробую узнать нет ли ошибок, то принтер либо ничего не отвечает, либо шлет только \0. Может быть кто-то уже работал с подобным оборудованием и встречался с такой проблемой?

```
serialPort2.PortName = "COM5";
            serialPort2.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort2.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort2.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            serialPort2.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            serialPort2.ReadTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort2.WriteTimeout = 10000;
            serialPort2.Open();
            //serialPort2.Close();
            //serialPort2 = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600,    System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8/*data bits*/, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One);
            serialPort2.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
            serialPort2.DataReceived += serialPort2_DataReceived;
```

отправка запроса состояния на принтер:

```
data = new byte[2];
data[0] = 27;
data[1] = (int)'v';
serialPort2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

запрос количества чернил:

```
data = new byte[2];
data[0] = 27;
data[1] = (int)'u';
serialPort2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

На первый запрос, если все нормально приходит ответ \0, если нет бумаги, то ничего не приходит, на второй вообще нет реакции